# Unix: How to delete files listed in a file

Tags: linux, unix

I have a long text file with list of file masks I want to delete

Example:

```
/tmp/aaa.jpg
/var/www1/*
/var/www/qwerty.php
```

I need delete them. Tried rm `cat 1.txt` and it says the list is too long.

Found this command, but when I check folders from the list, some of them still have files
`xargs rm <1.txt` Manual rm call removes files from such folders, so no issue with permissions.

Comment: Even though it's six years later: Would you mindaccepting one of the answers? This'll mark the question as resolved and help other users as well.

Answer (score 154):

This is not very efficient, but will work if you need glob patterns (as in /var/www/*)

```
for f in $(cat 1.txt) ; do 
  rm "$f"
done
```

If you don't have any patterns and are sure your paths in the file do not contain whitespaces or other weird things, you can use xargs like so:

```
xargs rm < 1.txt
```

Comment: What will happen with the first solution (using CAT) if the path contains a space?

Comment: This didn't work for me using MINGW64 Bash with a text file containing paths with spaces.

Comment: @804b18f832fb419fb142 Yep, same for me. Any alternatives?

Comment: To deal with white space, I suggest using a while loop with read function to solve this problem. A script with`filename='123.txt'; while read line ; rm -r "$line"; done < $filename`. Pay attention to the quote marks around $line. It is a gotcha point in shell scripting.

Answer (score 78):

Assuming that the list of files is in the file `1.txt`, then do:

```
xargs rm -r <1.txt
```

The `-r` option causes recursion into any directories named in `1.txt`.

If any files are read-only, use the `-f` option to force the deletion:

```
xargs rm -rf <1.txt
```

---

Be cautious with input to *any* tool that does programmatic deletions.  Make *certain* that the files named in the input file are really to be deleted.  Be especially careful about seemingly simple typos.  For example, if you enter a space between a file and its suffix, it will appear to be two separate file names:

```
file .txt
```

is actually two separate files: `file` and `.txt`.

This may not seem so dangerous, but if the typo is something like this:

```
myoldfiles *
```

Then instead of deleting all files that begin with `myoldfiles`, you'll end up deleting `myoldfiles` and **all** non-dot-files and directories in the current directory. Probably not what you wanted.

Comment: "myoldfiles /" or "/ tmp" even more disastrous with -rf. Note the space character next to the "/".

Comment: I think this is a dangerous answer, why use recurse if it's a list of *files*, coupled with forced deletion makes this a footgun

Comment: @CervEd Because sometimes a man needs to shoot himself in the foot to get the job done.

Answer (score 33):

Use this:

```
while IFS= read -r file ; do rm -- "$file" ; done < delete.list
```

If you need glob expansion you can omit quoting `$file`:

```
IFS=""
while read -r file ; do rm -- $file ; done < delete.list
```

But be warned that file names can contain "problematic" content and I would use the unquoted version. Imagine this pattern in the file

```
*
*/*
*/*/*
```

This would delete quite a lot from the current directory! I would encourage you to prepare the delete list in a way that glob patterns aren't required anymore, and then **use quoting** like in my first example.

Comment: This is currently the only answer that handles all of `/My Dir With Spaces/` `/Spaces and globs/*.txt`, `--file-with-leading-dashes`, and as a bonus it's POSIX and works on GNU/Linux, macOS and BSD.

Answer (score 21):

`xargs -I{} sh -c 'rm "{}"' < 1.txt` should do what you want.  Be careful with this command as one incorrect entry in that file could cause a lot of trouble.

This answer was edited after @tdavies pointed out that the original did not do shell expansion.

Comment: Thanks, but no need to delete folders, only files

Comment: The globs won't get expanded, as they are never 'seen' by the shell.

Comment: @tdavies wow - you're right.  This command (albeit a bit uglier) will work: `xargs -I{} sh -c 'rm {}' < 1.txt`

Comment: doesn't work if filename has single quotes

Comment: Edit: Now it also supports spaces

Answer (score 20):

You could use '\n' for define the new line character as delimiter.

```
xargs -d '\n' rm < 1.txt
```

Be careful with the -rf because it can delete what you don't want to if the 1.txt contains paths with spaces. That's why the new line delimiter a bit safer.

On BSD systems, you could use -0 option to use new line characters as delimiter like this:

```
xargs -0 rm < 1.txt
```

Comment: On OS X this gets me `xargs: illegal option -- d`

Comment: Good point. It seems there is no other option than `-0` on OS X.

Comment: `xargs -I_ rm _` also works in OS X :) see http://stackoverflow.com/a/39335402/266309

Comment: If using BSD xargs (where there's no `-d`), you can first convert newlines to nulls: `tr '\n' '\0' < 1.txt | xargs -0 rm`

Comment: you can also first run `xargs -d '\n' ls < 1.txt` or `xargs -d '\n' stat < 1.txt` to verify what will be deleted and avoid nasty surprises

Comment: @CervEd Good idea. I usually do something like this: `xargs -d '\n' echo rm < 1.txt`

Comment: @Ray using stat or find you get errors if the files don't exists, you don't have permission etc which I find helpful to verify the paths are correct etc

Answer (score 18):

You can use this one-liner:

```
cat 1.txt | xargs echo rm | sh
```

Which does shell expansion but executes `rm` the minimum number of times.

Comment: As long as any expansion isn't too long?

Comment: True, a glob could produce an argument list which is too long -- you can add the `-n <n>` argument to `xargs` to reduce the number of arguments passed to each rm, but that will still not protect you from a single glob which exceeds the limit.

Answer (score 8):

Just to provide an another way, you can also simply use the following command

```
$ cat to_remove
/tmp/file1
/tmp/file2
/tmp/file3
$ rm $( cat to_remove )
```

Comment: Works like a charm, also with `rm -r`. Deleted about 5TB of data this way. Can also be used with other commands, such as `ls` or `du`.

Comment: what about paths with spaces?

Answer (score 5):

`cat 1.txt | xargs rm -f | bash` Run the command will do the following for files only.

`cat 1.txt | xargs rm -rf | bash` Run the command will do the following recursive behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

In this particular case, due to the dangers cited in other answers, I would

1. Edit in e.g. Vim and `:%s/\s/\\\0/g`, escaping all space characters with a backslash.
2. Then `:%s/^/rm -rf /`, prepending the command. With `-r` you don't have to worry to have directories listed after the files contained therein, and with `-f` it won't complain due to missing files or duplicate entries.
3. Run all the commands: `$ source 1.txt`

Comment: Spaces are not the only characters which need escaping, popular in filenames are also brackets of any kind which can lead to unwanted expansion.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another looping example. This one also contains an 'if-statement' as an example of checking to see if the entry is a 'file' (or a 'directory' for example):

```
for f in $(cat 1.txt); do if [ -f $f ]; then rm $f; fi; done
```

Answer (score 1):

This will allow file names to have spaces (reproducible example).

```
# Select files of interest, here, only text files for ex.
find -type f -exec file {} \; > findresult.txt
grep ": ASCII text$" findresult.txt > textfiles.txt
# leave only the path to the file removing suffix and prefix
sed -i -e 's/:.*$//' textfiles.txt
sed -i -e 's/\.\///' textfiles.txt

#write a script that deletes the files in textfiles.txt
IFS_backup=$IFS
IFS=$(echo "\n\b")
for f in $(cat textfiles.txt); 
do 
rm "$f"; 
done
IFS=$IFS_backup

# save script as "some.sh" and run: sh some.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use set of folders from **deletelist.txt** while **avoiding some patterns** as well

```
foreach f (cat deletelist.txt)
    rm -rf ls | egrep -v "needthisfile|*.cpp|*.h"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody prefers `sed` and removing **without wildcard expansion**:

```
sed -e "s/^\(.*\)$/rm -f -- \'\1\'/" deletelist.txt | /bin/sh
```

**Reminder:** use absolute pathnames in the file or make sure you are in the right directory.

And for completeness the same with `awk`:

```
awk '{printf "rm -f -- '\''%s'\''\n",$1}' deletelist.txt | /bin/sh
```

Wildcard expansion will work if the single quotes are remove, but this is dangerous in case the filename contains spaces. This would need to add quotes around the wildcards.