# OS X: list and remove files with spaces

Tags: macos, bash

I'd like to do this in OS X:

```
ls -rt | xargs rm -i
```

However, `rm` is choking on the fact that some of the files have whitespaces.

I mention OS X because BSD's version of `ls` does not have a `-Q` flag.

Is there a way to do this without having to use `find -print0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```sh
while read -u 3
do
  rm -i "$REPLY"
done 3< <(ls -rt)
```

Comment: Assuming parsing `ls` output is acceptable and the number of files is small, this works well, except that there's no need for custom file descriptor `3`; just `< <(ls -rt)` and `read` without `-u 3` will do. Also, to be fully robust, `read -r`, should be used to avoid interpretation of backlashes.

Answer (score 5):

```
[sgeorge@sgeorge-ld staCK]$ touch "file name"{1..5}.txt
[sgeorge@sgeorge-ld staCK]$ ls -1
file name1.txt
file name2.txt
file name3.txt
file name4.txt
file name5.txt
[sgeorge@sgeorge-ld staCK]$ ls -rt | xargs -I {} rm -v {}
removed `file name5.txt'
removed `file name4.txt'
removed `file name3.txt'
removed `file name2.txt'
removed `file name1.txt'
```

**OR**

```
[sgeorge@sgeorge-ld staCK]$ ls -1
file a
file b
file c
file d

[sgeorge@sgeorge-ld staCK]$ OLDIFS=$IFS; IFS=$'\n'; for i in `ls -1`; do rm -i $i; done; IFS=$OLDIFS
rm: remove regular empty file `file a'? y
rm: remove regular empty file `file b'? y
rm: remove regular empty file `file c'? y
rm: remove regular empty file `file d'? y
```

Comment: ++ for the `xargs -I{} ` approach; the 2nd approach makes the literal filenames subject to (accidental) globbing, unless you also turn off globing with `set -f` (and restore it later).

Answer (score 2):

You have two options. You can either call xargs with the -0 option, which splits the input into arguments using NUL characters (`\0`) as delimiters:

```
ls -rt | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 rm -i
```

or you can use the -I option to split the input on newlines only (`\n`) and call the desired command once for each line of the input:

```
ls -rt | xargs -I_ rm -i _
```

The difference is that the first version only calls `rm` once, with all the arguments provided as a single list, while the second one calls `rm` individually for each line in the input.

Answer (score 1):

Just have find delete it for you.

```
find . -print -depth 1 -exec rm -i {} \;
```

It's more flexible, should be ok with spaces.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete all files, what's wrong with `rm -i *`?

[Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)