# Finding and deleting files using python script

Tags: linux, bash, python-2.7

I am writing a Python script to find and remove all .py files having corresponding .pyc files.
How to extract this file list and remove them?

For example : consider there some file in /foo/bar:

```
file.py
file.pyc
file3.py
file2.py
file2.pyc...etc
```

I want to delete file.py,file2.py and not file3.py  as it do not have corresponding .pyc file.
and I want to do in all folders under '/'.

Is there one-liner bash code for the same?

P.S : I am using CentOS 6.8, having python2.7

Comment: Interesting request. Are you sure you don't want to delete `.pyc` files that have corresponding `.py` files? :)

Comment: No, it is a client request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my solution:

```
    import os
    ab=[]
    for roots,dirs,files in os.walk("/home/foo/bar/"):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".py"):
                ab.append(os.path.join(roots,file))
    bc=[]
    for i in range(len(ab)):
        bc.append(ab[i]+"c")
    xy=[]
    for roots,dirs,files in os.walk("/home/foo/bar/"):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".pyc"):
                xy.append(os.path.join(roots,file))
    ex=[x[:-1] for x in bc if x in xy]
    for i in ex:
        os.remove(i)
```

P.S: Newbie in python scriptiing.

Answer (score 1):

Bash solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

find  /foo/bar -name "*.py" -exec ls  {} \;  > file1.txt
find  /foo/bar/ -name "*.pyc" -exec ls {} \; > file2.txt
p=`wc -l file1.txt| cut -d' ' -f1`
for ((c=1;c<=$p;c++))
do
  grep `sed -n ${c}p file1.txt | sed s/$/c/g` file2.txt > /dev/null
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]
     then
       list=`sed -n ${c}p file1.txt`
           echo " exist : $list"
           rm -rf `sed -n ${c}p file1.txt`
  fi
 done
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a very operating-system-near solution

maybe make a shell script from the following commands and invoke it from python using `subprocess.call` ([How to call a shell script from python code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777301/how-to-call-a-shell-script-from-python-code), [Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python))

`find . -name "*.pyc" > /tmp/pyc.txt`

`find . -name "*.py" > /tmp/py.txt`

from the entries of these files remove path and file ending using `sed` or `basename`:

`for f in $(cat /tmp/pyc.txt) ; do 
   sed 's/.*\///'  remove path 
   sed 's/\.[^.]*$//' remove file ending
done`

`for f in $(cat /tmp/py.txt) ; do 
   sed 's/.*\///'  remove path 
   sed 's/\.[^.]*$//' remove file ending
done`

(https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44735/how-to-get-only-filename-using-sed)

`awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next}($1 in a){print}' /tmp/pyc.txt /tmp/py.txt > /tmp/rm.txt` (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125155/compare-two-files-for-matching-lines-and-store-positive-results)

`for f in $(cat /tmp/rm.txt) ; do 
  rm $f
done` ([Unix: How to delete files listed in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142429/unix-how-to-delete-files-listed-in-a-file))

Comment: If possible I need one-liner code for the same?

Answer (score 0):

The following code will work for a single layer directory. (Note: I wasn't sure how you wanted to handle multiple layers of folders --- e.g. if you have `A.py` in one folder and `A.pyc` in another, does it count as having both present, or do they have to be in the same layer of the same folder? If the latter case, it should be fairly simple to just loop through the folders and just call this code within each loop.)

```
import os

# Produces a sorted list of all files in a directory
dirList = os.listdir(folder_path)   # Use os.listdir() if want current directory
dirList.sort()

# Takes advantage of fact that both py and pyc files will share same name and
# that pyc files will appear immediately after their py counterparts in dirList

lastPyName = ""

for file in dirList:
    if file[-3:] == ".py":
        lastPyName = file[:-3]
    elif file[-4:] == ".pyc":
        if lastPyName == file[:-4]:
            os.remove(lastPyName + ".py")
            os.remove(lastPyName + ".pyc") # In case you want to delete this too
```

Comment: code works fine. But sometimes in dirlist .pyc file comes first then .py,
For example:

`list[1]=argu.py
    list[2]=test1.pyc
    list[3]=self.py
    .
    .
    .
    list[10]=test.py`

will it cause any issue while comparing?

Comment: Try adding a sort after dirlist. E.g. `dirlist = sort(dirlist)` That should ensure that .pyc comes directly after its corresponding .py file.

Comment: To be clear, the python sorting syntax is `dirList.sort()`. I've added it to my code above.